# NodeJS installed modules are not recognized on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I need some help to setup NodeJS on a Windows 10 machine.

I installed the 10.15.3 LTS version from the official website which has done the following:

- Node installed at `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`
- Added to the Path in the user's variables: `C:\Users\rsantos\AppData\Roaming\npm`
- Added to the Path in the environment variables: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`
- Created an empty npm folder at: `C:\Users\rsantos\AppData\Roaming`

Then with `npm init` I initialized the package file which was created at `C:\Users\rsantos`.

Followed by `npm install supervisor` which:

- Created a npm-cache folder at `C:\Users\rsantos\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`
- Created a node_modules folder (with the supervisor) at `C:\Users\rsantos\node_modules`
- Created a `package-lock.json` file at `C:\Users\rsantos` with:

```
  {
    "name": "rsantos",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "lockfileVersion": 1,
    "requires": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "supervisor": {
        "version": "0.12.0",
        "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/supervisor/-/supervisor-0.12.0.tgz",
        "integrity": "sha1-3n5jNwFbKRhRwQ81OMSn8EkX7ME="
      }
    }
  }
```

- Updated the `package.json` file to:

```
  {
    "name": "rsantos",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "supervisor": "^0.12.0"
    }
  }
```

Then when I open the command line and type:

`C:\Users\rsantos\Desktop>supervisor --watch C:\NodeJS_Projects\Proj1\ -e js C:\NodeJS_Projects\Proj1\Test.js`

I get:

`'supervisor' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

After that I tried to install supervisor globally and it started to work. 
The next error was 'require' not being recognized after installed locally.
I followed the same approach which made supervisor work and installed require globally. My code is requiring the module with `require('request')`. But even installed globally, it fails with this error:

`Error: Cannot find module 'request' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)`

Notes:

- I uninstalled everything and reinstalled, the result was always the same.
- Also played with the environment variables but still no good.
- `npm list -g request` outputs this: `C:\Users\rsantos\AppData\Roaming\npm -- request@2.88.0`
- At this point my `C:\Users\rsantos\node_modules` folder has all the modules, including supervisor and request.
- The package.json has supervisor and request as dependencies.
- The package-lock.json seems to have all the modules in the node_modules folder, including supervisor and request.
- I still get the `Cannot find module 'request'` error.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you want to use a NPM package as tool (e.g. `>supervisor --watch PATH`), you can install the package `--global`. When you want to load the package in Node with `require()` I would install it locally.

Does the following work for you?

Install the tooling globally:

```
npm install --global supervisor
```

Set up your project in local folder:

```
mkdir project
cd project
npm init -y
npm install --save request     # install to project/node_modules
node index.js                  # start your app
```